# How to fix: Resources$NotFoundException while calling Toast

Tags: java, android, listview

I wanted to display the `Selecteditemposition` (number of clicked item in a `Listview`) in a `Toast` when an item is clicked in my `Listview`, but any method in this event crashes.

This is the crash report:

```
2019-06-27 20:54:02.681 13006-13015/? E/ample.basicipt: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
2019-06-27 20:54:17.470 13006-13006/com.example.basiciptv E/ample.basicipt: No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff.
2019-06-27 20:54:17.472 13006-13006/com.example.basiciptv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.basiciptv, PID: 13006
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:307)
        at com.example.basiciptv.MainActivity$4.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:336)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1192)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3169)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

And this is the code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        boolean co = true;
        int lineNumber = listview.getSelectedItemPosition();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lineNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lineNumber` is an integer, so you are using  this overload of `makeText()`:

```
makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)
```

Which expects an integer string resource id, so `lineNumber` is considered a string resource id, which of course is not so it can't be found.

Instead what you should be doing is convert `lineNumber` to string and use this overload of `makeText()`:

```
makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

So do this:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(lineNumber), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

So linenumber is already returned onclick method as position.

```
Toast.maketext(getApplicationContext,position.toString(), Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
```